# How enable Deblocking Filter in ffmpeg h264 Encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, codec, encoder

I am new to ffmpeg. I have searched Stack Overflow for this question, but was not able to get the exact answer.

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:./FFMPEGEncLibs
>   ./ffmpegEnc -f rawvideo -r 60 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec rawvideo -i ./encIn/piglab_1frames.yuv -c:v libx264 -x264-params cabac=0:8x8dct=0 -pix_fmt yuv422p -profile:v high422 -psnr -intra -qp 9 ./encOut/EncOut_1frames.h264
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:./FFMPEGDecLibs
>   ./ffmpegDec -f h264 -i ./encOut/piglab_EncOut_1frames.h264 ./decOut/DecOut_1frames.yuv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deblocking filter (assuming you mean the one part of the h264 standard) is automatically enabled in x264. To control the loopfilter parameters, use the "deblock" private codec option:

```
Loop filter parameters, in <alpha:beta> form.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Ronald. where should I enable this command, is it inside my make file.

Comment: Add it inside the -x264-params flag in your command: " ./ffmpegEnc -f rawvideo -r 60 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec rawvideo -i ./encIn/piglab_1frames.yuv -c:v libx264 -x264-params cabac=0:8x8dct=0 -pix_fmt yuv422p -profile:v high422 -psnr -intra -qp 9 ./encOut/EncOut_1frames.h264", e.g. something like -x264-params cabac=0:8x8dct=0:deblock=2\\:2. Both alpha and beta take an integer in the range -6 to 6, where -6 means "light filter" and 6 means "heavy filter". I'm escaping the : because ffmpeg also uses it as a separator and I'm hoping this will prevent ffmpeg from parsing it. (Untested!)

Comment: thanks for the answer, that was very helpful. One More doubt I have is how to disable Deblocking filter. If I add -no-deblock, its giving an error. How can I disable deblocking filter ?

Comment: "-x264-params no-deblock=1", I believe. Or maybe it's "-x264-params no-deblock"

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje You should put that comment into the answer, because as is the answer makes no sense. Is it necessary to include the `cabac` filter whenever using `-x264-params`, or is it irrelevant to the `deblock` filter?

Comment: cabac is irrelevant to deblock: it's a type of bitstream generation using an entropy model, the other one - without entropy model - would be cavlc. The OP question's commandline invocation used it already so I kept it there.